# UINavigationController height is zero when embedded as child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I have an app where a `UIView` containing a child `UIViewController` slides up from the bottom.
The child controller defines the height via autolayout.

Here's my working code:

```
// controller is new added controller
addChildViewController(controller)

controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomSheetViewContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomSheetViewContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

// Setting only top, left, right anchors so the view isn't squished on sliding up
controller.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
controller.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

// This calculates the correct height
bottomSheetViewContainerView.layoutIfNeeded()
print("controller.view.bounds.height: \(controller.view.bounds.height)")

bottomSheetViewContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: controller.view.bounds.height).isActive = true

// bottomSheetContainerView slides up
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.40) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now i wanted to embed the existing child controller in an `UINavigationController` before the animation. But when I do this, the height is zero. Somehow it doesn't get the height of the top ViewController...

Also the `topViewController` has zero height. How can I force calculate its height?

Answer (score 0):

// Setting only top, left, right anchors so the view isn't squished on sliding up

```
controller.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
controller.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSheetViewContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

You should add **bottom >= 0 constraint**

and remove

```
bottomSheetViewContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: controller.view.bounds.height).isActive = true
```

If constraints inside controller view are correct it should work.

Comment: I think you need to add this line of code controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not working either. I get ton's of breaking layout constraints log messages. But they're not appearing when the controller is directly added with my code above and not embedded in navigation controller. So my controller should be fine